# ASP Net core: websockets performance

Tags: nginx, websocket, asp.net-core, kestrel

What is current state of websockets performance on kestrel:
1. How maximum connections it can hold?
2. Is there any tips for how to improve kestrel websockets performance?
3. Does kestrel 2.0.0-preview have strong performance improvement of ws?

We are using nginx as reserved proxy before kestrel, are there any suggestions of how to get more simultaneously connections? Now we can reach 100000 connection whith 3-5 handshaking timeout.